# Chrome extension to copy current URL and open tab to perform actions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extensions and trying to work this out.

When I click on the extension button, it should copy the current url and open google.com in a new tab then place this url in searchbox or console print the url. Basically, 
Copy the url to new tab, which can be used to perform further actions.

We can open new tab using.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var action_url = "http://www.google.com"
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: action_url });
  });
```

Not sure how to call functions/perform actions after the new tab openx

Comment: Read the [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). You will need a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to perform operations in the opened tab.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do two things :
1) Copy the current url.
2) Do something with it in the new tab opened with google.com as the url.

You can get the current url in javascript using: window.location.href
You have a callback function for chrome.tabs.create(object createProperties, function callback) as [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onCreated) and use this callback function ( which is called once the tab is successfully created)  to pass current url to content script using [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).